# Would be great to get a detailed error description table for Flattr API

Tags: flattr

In general it would be great to get some sort of description of all possible errors returned by the API for any particular request. This would make implementations much more reliable and would improved the application feedback for the user.

Imagine that we need to display localized error messages to the user and not only "Request failed with error code xxx".

A good example is this error `{"error":"flattr_once","error_description":"You are not allowed to flattr this thing more than once this period","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"}`. There is no mention of it in the documentation, but an application needs to make sense of that and maybe refrain from giving the user the option to flattr this item in the future.

Comment: I have started to include errors in the documentation. Check out the /thing/:id/Flattr resource for a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several error descriptions in the developer documentation. For example error responses when a [flattring failed](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#flattr-a-thing) and the [standard errors](http://developers.flattr.net/api/#client-errors) that are universal to many of the resources.

Answer (score 1):

This is some responses I found when flattering around:

403 `{"error":"flattr_once","error_description":"You are not allowed to flattr this thing more than once this period","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"}`

401 `{"error":"no_means","error_description":"You don't have any money to flattr with","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"}`

`{"error":"flattr_owner","error_description":"You are not allowed to flattr your own thing","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"}`